# What does overloading the parentheses operator do?

Tags: c++, class, overloading, parentheses

I see this very often and I'm wondering what it does/its purpose.

1. What does overloading operator() do?
2. Why do people usually overload this operator?

***Example***

```
std::vector<double> operator()(int seed) const;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Functors and matrix indexing](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/99-overloading-the-parenthesis-operator/) are, to my knowledge, the most common use cases.

**Matrix Indexing**
For a matrix class, you can do something like this:

```
Matrix3x3 A;
A(1,2) = 2;
```

The main reason that parentheses are used instead of brackets in this case is that the brackets operator only accepts one argument while the parentheses operator accepts multiple arguments.

**Functor**
If you want an object to act as a function that can also store information, you can do:

```
Accumulator accumulate;
for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
    accumulate(i);
std::cout << accumulate.sum << std::endl;
```

In C++, you will also often encounter functors for [comparator objects](https://thispointer.com/c-how-to-sort-a-list-of-objects-with-custom-comparator-or-lambda-function/), even though they do not store information.

Comment: Should probably mention that the reason this is done for matrix indexing is because the index operator only allows *exactly* one argument, whereas parens can take any number

Comment: @CruzJean You're right. I will edit my answer. Thanks!